# Select into output in where statement

Tags: sas

I would like to use `where` statement in proc sql to select variables found in column `x` which has been assigned to macro variable `&grades`.

Here is example which doesn't work and needs to be fixed:

```
data work.data;
    input x$ y;
    datalines;
    a 1
    a .
    b 2
    c 3
    ;
run;

proc sql; select distinct x into :grades separated by ' ' from work.data; quit;

%put &grades; *--- I'M MISSING QUOTES AROUND THE VALUES??;

proc sql; select * from work.data where x in (&grades); quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add quotes to a value use the `quote()` function.

```
select distinct quote(x)
  into :grades separated by ' ' 
  from work.data
;
```